# Ordering a list based on multiple factors

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given the following classes:

```
public class Room
{
    public List<Person> People {get;set;}
    public string RoomType {get;set;}
}

public class Person
{
    public bool IsLead{get;set;}
}
```

Given I have a list of Rooms that contains a list of People, how can I order them in such a way that

- The first room in the ordered list be the one that the lead is in.
- All rooms of the same type follow each other

Note that there is only ever one person who is lead.

Example data:

- doubleroom nonlead
- singleroom nonlead
- singleroom lead
- doubleroom nonlead

ordered:

- singleroom lead
- singleroom nonlead
- doubleroom nonlead
- doubleroom nonlead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple, efficient approach:

```
var orderedRooms = rooms
    .OrderBy(room => !room.People.Any(person => person.IsLead)) // room with lead will be first
    .GroupBy(room => room.RoomType) // RoomType with lead will be first
    .SelectMany(group => group); // flatten the list of groups into one list
```

This query meets the following requirements:

- The first room in the ordered list is the one that the lead is in.
- All rooms of the same type follow each other.

However, it does *not* sort the room types alphabetically.

Comment: This is great. I have no need for the rooms to be sorted alphabetically

Comment: @GrantWinney's approach allowed having the leader room as a variable for further use, which could have proved practical. It was an useful answer too IMHO. But otherwise this one's prettier. :)